# Canvas as string with maximum compression?

Tags: javascript, canvas, compression, base64, html2canvas

I have a PNG image and got its Base64 PNG string representation. It's still quite large and i'd like to know if it can be significantly further compressed. Is that even possible?

Background

I am using html2canvas to create a screenshot of the current web page, convert it as base64 (using canvas.toDataURL())string and send that to server.But if that string size is too large, the server returns an Exception.

What is the most efficient way of compressing the canvas in the form of string?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to compress the string, I recommend using a compression library such as http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript on the client side to compress and http://webdevwonders.com/lzw-compression-and-decompression-with-javascript-and-php/ on the server side to decompress (assuming you use php). This method has the advantage of working on both the client and server side, and uses the well-regarded LZW algorithm.

Comment: Well regarded?  LZW is obsolete.  Other compression techniques are faster and compress better.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, that compression will, in most cases use dictionaries or other methods to compress the data. This will consider in even bigger compressed data if the base string cannot be compressed really good. You have to find a picture size which will result in a smaller size after compression!

Maybe another approach would help. Can't the server do the html2canvas for you if you send only the URL? Could you split the data into smaller buffers and then try to send them? Maybe you should loop over the size of your data, split it into 64 KB buffers and transmit them (keeping in mind that you need to verify on the server side which buffer belongs towhich packet).

Otherwise try the GZIP, LZW, LZMA algorithms. Maybe you could also use a tool to compress the image which html2canvas creates?

Comment: The problem is  client side code is in javascript from where the canvas data needs to posted as string to java service .Instead of sending chunk by chunk from client side,and aggregating at java side if I could compress the canvas and send then it would be more easy.

Comment: Yes, indeed, sending at once with javascript on client side would be easier. Feel free to try compression but keep in mind that it will do a better job on bigger data. You cannot send the URL to the server so that the server can do the html2canvas for you?

Comment: Thanks Dustin for the quick reply.No.I have the html2canvas library packed in my application.I am just passing the element which I need to capture.The html2canvas returns the canvas which currently is being converted to base 64 format using toDataUrl() which will give the string in png form.On this can I do further compression?.If not then directly on canvas I cannot apply compression logic right?.So I have to convert the canvas to normal string first.Any idea on this?

Comment: Maybe you can try to estimate the max string size you can pass to your server. Any time your string is too long you should try to compress the base64 string. But it could happen that this string is still too big... Another approach would be to set maxPostSize to a higher value so your server will accept more data (?)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't get there from here.  You will likely need to find a different way to get the image over, and not try to stuff it in to a URL.

For small gains, you can try [pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) to make the PNG image smaller, or more violently to simply reduce the size of the PNG image directly by reducing the resolution and/or number of colors.

You can also use a different encoding scheme than Base64 to squeeze out a few more characters by using more than 64 encoding characters.  There are 66 unreserved characters you can use, plus you can likely use many of the 18 reserved characters, depending on the syntax of your URL.

But aside from changing the image itself, you will only realize small gains.